# Citations in LaTex beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I have trouble getting any kind of citation working with **latex beamer** and the **biblatex** package. I considered at least 30 different approaches proposed here and in other forums.
Because I used `\cite` in my thesis, I would like to stick with biblatex and `\cite`. This is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[presentation, notes = show]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\usepackage{biblatex}

% nothing of the following seems to work

\bibliography{bib.bib}
%\bibliography{bib}
%\addbibresource{bib.bib}
%\addbibresource{bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        \cite{test}
        \footfullcite{test}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output I get is [test ]^1 and a footnote 1: test.

Comment: Your code works for me. Do you run `biber` after `pdflatex`? Have you tried put the `bib` file in the same folder/directory as the main file?

Comment: I did not explicitely run biber, but BibTex (worked with non-beamer document), now I run biber. It seems to do stuff: `INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bib.bib'`, but after running `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, I still see only the citation keys.

Comment: You can use `bibtex` instead of `biber`. For this use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`. Also I would suggest to remove all auxiliary files first.

Comment: The `biblatex` syntax is `\addbibresourec{bib.bib}` and then call `biber`.  Does `biber` report any undefined keys?

Answer (score 3):

Try setup a style:

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

or

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

See the `biblatex` documentation to see the styles avaiable.

another suggestion not related to the question. You can replace `notes=show` to `shownotes` to avoid a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is not the answer to your question, but it is too long to put it in the comment. What kind of advantage you want from using bib bibliography in presentation? Presentations usually mean few (three maximum) references per slide and the usual machinery (track order, etc) is just distracting here. For my presentations I use the following construction:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[calc]{picture}

\newcommand{\mycite}[2][0]{%
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
\put(0.95\paperwidth,0.07\paperheight + 12pt * {#1}){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\color{black!60!white!30!green}{\tiny{\rmfamily{ #2 }}}}}}%
}
```

And then just put `\mycite{Mr. Smith, THE_JOURNAL {\bf 00}, 000000 (0000)}` on the slides. Additional parameter to the command allows to stack those references.

Could you explain in more details, how exactly you want `\cite` behave in your beamer presentation? How it would understand the format you desire for this particular reference, how many authors and which (most likely, non-standard) abbreviation you use for the journal to fit in the presentation page, etc?

Comment: I want to use \cite as I can in non-beamer documents. It is supposed to work with latex beamer in the same way. It can be configured to fit the format I prefer.

Comment: A good reason to use citation commands rather than a manual approach is consistency between slides.  If you're maintaining a correct .bib file, using that as a source directly makes more sense than copy-pasting into your beamer document

Answer (score 0):

In case if somebody is still looking for a solution, this worked for me:

```
    \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{doc}
```

I had above 2 lines before starting the document and I had all my citations in my doc.bib file. I use Texmaker IDE, I first open doc.bib file and run the `BibTex` option from the drop down menu 3-4 times and then load the .tex file and run it with the `BibTex` option 3-4 times and then change the drop down to `Quick Build` and then compile the document couple of times and I have the footnote citation.

Comment: You should be able to use Biber (i.e. `backend=biber` or the default if no `backend` is specified) if you tell your editor to use Biber as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. There should usually be no need to switch to BibTeX nowadays. Note that `biblatex` will only allow you to use a limited set of features when you use `backend=bibtex`. The really cool stuff (Unicode sorting, dynamic data model, source maps ...) only works with Biber